# What's the most efficient way to load and extract 32 bit integer values from a 128 bit SSE vector?

Tags: c, gcc, sse, simd

I'm trying to optimize my code using SSE intrinsics but am running into a problem where I don't know of a good way to extract the integer values from a vector after I've done the SSE intrinsics operations to get what I want.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this? I'm programming in C and my compiler is gcc version 4.3.2.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hmm... `int *pointer = vectoraddress; *(pointer++) four times`?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't do all of your operations in the SSE registers and then just dump them back to memory when you're done?

Comment: I tried but I kept getting some compilation errors that I couldn't quite figure out...

Comment: Maybe you should post your code to give people a better idea of what it is that you are actually trying to achieve with SSE ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you can assume about the minimum level of SSE support that you have.

Going all the way back to SSE2 you have `_mm_extract_epi16` (`PEXTRW`) which can be used to extract any 16 bit element from a 128 bit vector. You would need to call this twice to get the two halves of a 32 bit element.

In more recent versions of SSE (SSE4.1 and later) you have `_mm_extract_epi32` (`PEXTRD`) which can extract a 32 bit element in one instruction.

Alternatively if this is not inside a performance-critical loop you can just use a union, e.g.

```
typedef union
{
    __m128i v;
    int32_t a[4];
} U32;
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your reply. Where did you find those functions (mm_extract_epi16/32)? I don't see them in the gcc documentation. Including -mmmx -msse -msse2 and -msse3 don't seem to let me use it and the compiler says that there is an implicit function declaration.

Comment: @Kaigi: `_mm_extract_epi16` is in emmintrin.h, `_mm_extract_epi32` is in smmintrin.h. You'll need a reasonably up to date version of gcc for the latter.

Answer (score 6):

```
_mm_extract_epi32
```

The extract intrinsics is indeed the best option but if you need to support SSE2, I'd recommend this:

```
inline int get_x(const __m128i& vec){return _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (vec);}
inline int get_y(const __m128i& vec){return _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (_mm_shuffle_epi32(vec,0x55));}
inline int get_z(const __m128i& vec){return _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (_mm_shuffle_epi32(vec,0xAA));}
inline int get_w(const __m128i& vec){return _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (_mm_shuffle_epi32(vec,0xFF));}
```

I've found that if you reinterpret_cast/union the vector to any int[4] representation the compiler tends to flush things back to memory (which may not be that bad) and reads it back as an int, though I haven't  looked at the assembly to see if the latest versions of the compilers generate better code.