# Can plain array be put in cpu register?

Tags: c++, c++11, cpu-registers

Can a plain array (`arr`) be put into cpu register in the following situation:

```
int arr[6] {/*some values*/};
const auto lambda_f = [arr](int input) {/*some manipulations on array elements and input*/};
// further usage of lambda_f
```

If it can't, how should I rewrite the code to make it possible?

EDIT: Of course, I've meant the copy of the array in the lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes.  But it depends on the particular platform.  If you have a very recent Intel x86-64 chip it will have "AVX2" instructions which operate on 256-bit (32 byte) integers.

Your `int arr[6]` is 4*6=24 bytes, so it will fit in a single AVX register, and then you can use AVX2 integer instructions on it.  You'll just need to ignore the extra 8 bytes of the register, but that's usually not a problem.

If you need to support older processors, you can use SSE2 instead, which will work on most any modern-ish x86 system.  You can only operate on 128 bits (4 ints) at a time though.

The first step is loading your data into a wide register.  For examples, see here: [What's the most efficient way to load and extract 32 bit integer values from a 128 bit SSE vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360920/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-load-and-extract-32-bit-integer-values-from-a-1)

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms, `int[6]` is too much information to put in a single register, though of course you could have pointers into the array in registers suitable for holding pointers.  Or if you mean to ask whether the contents of the array could be stored in some set of registers, it could be possible.

But it all depends on how the data is used, and whether or not the compiler thinks the registers are more valuable for other data.  If I can assume your posted code is actually inside a function block, any optimizing compiler would ignore your posted code entirely and get rid of both `arr` and `lambda_f`, since you never use them.

The only way to determine the answer is to try it out on specific actual code that does use `lambda_f`, and examine the resulting assembly.